# WordPress : Get Average of value from meta box

Tags: wordpress, metadata, average

I have more than one record in database for same `meta_key` like this :

```
meta_id    post_id    meta_key             meta_value
22176      1593       player_rat_1593      10
25246      1594       player_rat_1593      5
22186      1539       player_rat_1593      10
25288      1595       player_rat_1593      5
```

How can calculate it to get Average and print it in page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a SQL query like this:

```
global $wpdb
$average = $wpdb->get_val( "SELECT AVERAGE(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='player_rat_1593' ");
```